# Openstreetmap how to get the shortest travel distance by car between multiple points and a target

Tags: openstreetmap, cloudmade

i need to know the shortest distance (traveling by car on the map, not bird view) between let's say 10 GIS points and a target with possibly CloudMade or something else.

The points are within 10 kilometers.

So I need a way to know out of my 10 positions, which one is the closest to my target, that is travelling by car, not bird view.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you're developing a web app, an offline app, or something else. In general, you'll need to use a routing service, or routing code - see, for example, [MapQuest's web APIs](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/quick_start) or [Project OSRM's code](http://project-osrm.org/).

Then do a query for each and compare the distances. There aren't generally services that answer the question "which of these POIs is nearest?" AFAIK, so this is probably the most effective way to find which-is-nearest.

Comment: I knew that if i did the route on each i could take the smallest, but was hoping for an all in one solution since it may be done for 5 - 10 pos 10 to 15 shots in a row on a small scale, and on a larger scale ... not sure. Your OSRM code solution is nice and maintained !!! is that the best code or solution out there he says about 15 ms for each search ??